# How to define a nullable delegate member in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I need to decorate an instance in Java and would like the delegation to be in Kotlin (easier).

The problem is that I get a compilation error on the definition.

How can I define `inner` to be able to receive null?

```
open class ConnectionDecorator(var inner: Connection?) : Connection by inner // Getting an error on the right inner
```

Example usage from Java:

```
new ConnectionDecorator(null).close();
```

* This is a simplified example, trying to use Kotlin's delegation in Java, where passed content can be null.

Comment: It's "easier" in Kotlin but you can't get it to work? ;)

Comment: :) Easier by not needing to override all interface methods and delegate to the inner instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a [Null Connection Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) if the `inner` is null, for example:

```
//                             v--- the `var` is unnecessary
open class ConnectionDecorator(var inner: Connection?) : Connection by wrap(inner)


fun wrap(connection: Connection?): Connection = when (connection) {
    null -> TODO("create a Null Object") 
    else -> connection
}
```

In fact, there is no need such a `ConnectionDecorator`, it doesn't make sense, because when you using delegation you also need override some methods to provide additional operations, e.g:`log`. you can use `wrap` method directly, for example:

```
val connection:Connection? = null;

wrap(connection).close()
```

You should make the `inner` to **non-nullable** and create `ConnectionDecorator` instance by `wrap`, for example:

```
//                                        v--- make it to non-nullable
open class ConnectionDecorator(var inner: Connection) : Connection by inner {
    fun close(){
       inner.close();
       log.debug("connection is closed");
    }
}

val source:Connection? = null;

//                                          v--- wrap the source
val target:Connection = ConnectionDecorator(wrap(source))

target.close()
```

Comment: `TODO("create a Null Object")` - how to I create a null object?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka implements all methods of the `Connection` with empty body or return `a default value` of that method.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka sir, I'm not good at english, you can easily provide a `Null Object` by stub utils in java.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

ConnectionDecorator(null).close();

open class ConnectionDecorator(var inner: Connection?) : Connection by inner!!

Hope its work